# Connecting flight in Chicago

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, connecting-flights, ord

I am traveling from Delhi to London to Chicago to Pittsburgh with British Airways. It's a single ticket. I have a terminal change at Chicago airport and I have a 2-hour window to do so. Is the time window sufficient? Also, can you specify the steps involved in the process?

Thank you.

Comment: Given that you also have to go through immigration and customs, pick up your luggage and recheck it, i would say this is only doable, if you travel in first or business class and are one of the first to leave the plane (except if you have something like Global Entry, which will speed up your immigration).

Comment: @dunni That's overly pessimistic. Things _could_ go wrong on a 2hr connection but it'll probably be fine. The only part that takes time is immigration/customs. By the time you're through immigration, your bag will already be on the belt (pretty sure it has been every one of the 15-or-so times I've flown to the US) and rechecking it literally means handing it to an airline employee at the other side of customs, with zero queueing. (And this is why we want people to post answers as answers, not comments -- there's no way to downvote a wrong answer when it's a comment.)

Answer (score 2):

Step by Step instructions for international arrival: https://www.flychicago.com/ohare/myflight/international/pages/default.aspx

Step by Step transfer guide: https://www.flychicago.com/SiteCollectionDocuments/O%27Hare/MyFlight/TransferGuide.pdf

It's a tight connection and hard to predict. It really depends on how much time you will need to get through immigration, get your bags and through customs.

The good news: it's a single ticket and hence a "legal" connection. If you miss your flight BA (or their US domestic partner) will re-book on the next available flight for free. Assuming it's American Airlines (One World Partner for BA), there are 5 non-stops a day with the latest one leaving at 9:38pm